# How to fix "is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'X'"

Tags: typescript

I have a type I'm using in a generic constraint, e.g.

```
type Info = {
    userId: string;
    info: string;
}
```

I then define a generic type on `Info` without userId:

```
type InfoWithoutUser<T extends Info> = Omit<T, 'userId'>;
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to write a function that converts a generic `InfoWithoutUser` to `Info`. The way I'm attempting this is:

```
function convert<T extends Info>(input: InfoWithoutUser<T>): T {
    return Object.assign(input, { userId: 'test' });
}
```

However, TypeScript complains about this:

`'InfoWithoutUser<T> & { userId: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Info'.`

I disagree with this error message. The returned should match the subtype of the `T` parameter exactly. How can I get TypeScript to accept this?

Edit: Thinking about this a little more, I think the issue is that you could have implementations of `InfoWithoutUser` like this:

```
class MyInfoWithoutUser {
    info: string = 'info'

    myFunc() { ... }
}
```

In this case, using `Object.assign` would not preserve the subtype `T`. Is there a way to enforce that the generic constraint extends an interface and is also an object?

Comment: There are more specific types than `string`, like string literal types.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wey5Bw).  A `BobInfo` always has a `userId` of `"bob"`.  Your `convert()` purports to return a `BobInfo` if called a certain way, but it does not do so.  The fix is not to insist that you can turn any `Omit<T, "userId">` into a `T`, but to claim that you can turn any `T extends Omit<Info, "userId">` into a `T & {userId: string}`.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?